# After adding react-router-dom my github pages showing nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

After added react-router-dom I pushed it to the GitHub `https://github.com/iamtheasad/user`. In the project url my homepage are showing `https://iamtheasad.github.io/user/`, after that I click to another menu item it's redirecting to another page but while I refresh another page it's showing 404 page, click on home it took me to this link `https://iamtheasad.github.io/` and it's showing me blank white page.

My navigation component link: `https://github.com/iamtheasad/user/tree/master/src/components/TopNavigation`

My Router Component Link: `https://github.com/iamtheasad/user/tree/master/src/router`

I am trying to do add these: `<NavLink exact activeStyle={{color: '#00a8ee'}} className={this.state.navBarItem} to={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/'}>Home</NavLink> </Nav.Link>`

and

```
<Route exact path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/'} component={HomePage}/>
                <Route exact path="/service" component={ServicePage}/>
                <Route exact path="/course" component={CoursesPage}/>
                <Route exact path="/portfolio" component={PortfolioPage}/>
                <Route exact path="/contact" component={ContactPage}/>
                <Route exact path="/about" component={AboutPage}/>
```

[image]

Comment: Try removing `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` from `to` prop in the `NavLink` component, as far as I know links are relative

Comment: I just tried it. It didn't work.

Comment: You need to show the complete code of your routes file, where you are rendering Route component.

Comment: This is my router file link `https://github.com/iamtheasad/user/blob/master/src/router/AppRoute.js`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `homepage` property in `package.json` file at room level.

package.json

```
{
    "homepage": "https://iamtheasad.github.io/user"
}
```

`user` being the name of repository

Comment: I already added this - "homepage": "https://iamtheasad.github.io/user/"

Answer (score 0):

react-router is a client base router. To solve this problem you need to fix the server base router. When user go to URL like www.user.github.io/repo github will try to serve the `repo/index.html` in the github page repository to the user. If that file does not exist then they will return a 404.html page, and they also provide a way for you to have a custom 404 page.

Comment: So what should I do now?

Comment: Your method requires you to enable the pdf worker on your server. Use the example under basic usage from this link. https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf